# WaitAny and WaitAll waiting algorithms under the hood (order of check tasks)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I need to understand in general/simple terms the algorithm for waiting for completion of tasks for wait methods (`Task.WaitAny` and `Task.WaitAll`). I don't know the language well enough to dig into the source code. I tried, but I got completely confused. I got to the point where both methods can call method AddCompletionAction.

For me, this is redundant information and I expect to get a simple answer according to the algorithm.

**Question**. *How, in general terms, is the completion of tasks checked in the specified methods?*

For example:

WaitAny checks IsCompleted of each task with a delay in time and when IsCompleted of any task is true, the method exits.

WaitAll checks IsCompleted of each task with a delay in time and when IsCompleted is true then this task is excluded from the following checks. Or WaitAll checks IsCompleted of conditionally first task, and until IsCompleted false, the others task will not be checked.

These are all my guesses and it's hard for me to figure out the source code of the framework.
The answer is needed in simple words, as I wrote. There is no need to describe the operation of the entire method, affect the cancellation token, and so on. Interested only order of check tasks.

Comment: You could have a look at the sources of Task: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5041

Comment: The [core method](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5180) does not look very difficult to read, does it? It sets "signal this event" as CompletionAction for each task. When a task completes, the event signals. When the event is signaled as many times as there were tasks, the wait completes.

Comment: @GSerg, Yes, sorry, this is quite obvious, how did I not immediately understand this? Maybe because I'm just learning the language and couldn't figure it out, and I wrote about it above, but most likely I'm just an idiot. But you are clearly not like that, since you were able to figure it out and for you it is so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer your question with simple code instead of simple words. Here is how the two methods `WaitAny` and `WaitAll` could be implemented by someone who understood the basic mechanism, but who also had a total indifference for getting the details correctly:

```
// For demonstration purposes only. This code is rubbish.
static Task MyWaitAny(params Task[] tasks)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t => tcs.SetResult(t));
    }
    return tcs.Task.Result;
}

// For demonstration purposes only. This code is rubbish.
static void MyWaitAll(params Task[] tasks)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    int completedCount = 0;
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            completedCount++;
            if (completedCount == tasks.Length) tcs.SetResult();
        });
    }
    tcs.Task.Wait();
}
```

The `MyWaitAny` starts by creating a `TaskCompletionSource<Task>`. This is the mechanism that will propagate the `Task` that completed first. Then a continuation is attached to each `Task` in the `tasks`. This continuation just completes immediately the [`TaskCompletionSource<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1). Finally the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.task) property of the `TaskCompletionSource<Task>` is waited by invoking the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result).

The `MyWaitAll` starts by creating a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource). This mechanism will not propagate anything. It is created just for the purpose of waiting its [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource.task) property. Then a continuation is attached to each `Task` in the `tasks`. This continuation increments a counter, and when the counter reaches the `tasks.Length` it means that all tasks are completed, and so the `TaskCompletionSource` is completed too. Finally the `Task` property of the `TaskCompletionSource` is waited by invoking the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait).

**Note:** be aware that the code above is so far away from being production-ready, that it's not even funny. If you have any temptation about fixing it, please don't. You might be able to fix half a dozen problems, and many other problems will be still there.

Answer (score 2):

The basic premise is that both methods cycle through the list of `Task`s and assign a completion trigger to each `Task` - it keeps a count of how many items hit the completion trigger.

This is where you hit the difference between the two - if it's `WaitAny` then the first time that completion trigger is hit (i.e. whichever `Task` just so happens to finish quickest); it returns and goes back to whatever method called the `WaitAny`.

`WaitAll` only returns once the count of the completed `Task`s matches the count of the original `Task`s passed in to the method.

You've got your wires crossed - it's not intermittently checking for completion; it's waiting for it. Similar to in racing, it's not that the finish line intermittently checks for things crossing it - there's a beam across it, when someone crosses the line, they break the beam and the beam being broken triggers the lap/race completion process.